# Rails 4.0 undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Insert obligatory "I'm a Rails newbie" comment here.

**TL;DR: Cannot .create or .new instance of a model**

My basic structure is that Users are supposed to be able to have multiple notes which will have attachments handled by the "paperclip" gem. However, I can't seem to be able to actually create a note:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @note = @user.notes.create(params[:note].permit(:topic, :class, :content))

    redirect_to user_path(@user)
end
```

This is coming from the Note Controller and the error occurs in the line where I use @user.notes.create. What I've boiled the problem down to is that notes is empty at the beginning and for some reason the "create" call is failing on the empty notes array. Interestingly enough, Note.new also fails with the same error if I just try to instantiate an empty note to work with.

Models for reference:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :content,
    :storage => 's3',
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :path => "uploads/:attachment/:id/:styles.:extension",
    :styles => {
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :thumb => "100x100>" },
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] },
    :s3_permissions => 'public-read'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :notes

    validates_presence_of :username
    validates_presence_of :email
    validates_presence_of :school
    validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]    {2,4}\z/i

end
```

Let me know if any more info is needed, first time Rails user, first time Stack Exchange poster :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that your `class` column is causing major problems. I would generally treat `class` as a "reserved word" in Rails and never use it for a column name. (When I just tried creating a test model with a `class` column, I couldn't even get the form for it to load without getting a `stack level too deep` error).